# Power Automate, Delete file from blob storage

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, power-automate, blobstorage

Is there a way or a template that can be used within Power Automate that will remove a file from an azure blob container.

[image: Power Automate Flow]

I have a flow that creates a file in SharePoint once it has been added to Blob storage container but I want to remove the file then from the container after it is created in SharePoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Delete blob(V2)` action right after the SharePoint's `Create file` step and mention **path** to the blob from the trigger action. Below is the flow of my logic app.

[image]

***RESULTS:***

[image]